# Looping through subdirectories, reshaping matrix and saving output in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, reshape

I have a project folder (project1) which contains data from 20 Subjects (Sub-001, Sub-002 etc.). Each Subject's folder contains a subfolder (named AD) which has an AD.csv correlation matrix inside.

The folder structure looks like this

```
                                            ├── Sub-001
                                            │   └── AD
                                            │       └── AD.csv
                                            └── Sub-002
                                                └── *
```

I want to write a for loop that iteratively goes into each Subject's AD folder, reshapes the AD.csv matrix from wide to long, and saves the reshaped matrix as a new subj_AD_reshaped.csv file, named after the subject's ID (e.g., Sub-001_AD_reshaped.csv), in the Subject's folder.

The code I have written:

```
files<-list.files("group/S/project1/")
subjects<-list.dirs(path=files, full.names=T, recursive=F)
subj.AD<-subjects/"AD"

for (subj.AD in 1:length(subjects)) {
        df<-read.csv("matrix.csv", sep="", header=F)
        df.matrix<-as.matrix(df)
        df.matrix[lower.tri(df.matrix)]<-NA
        df.matrix.melt<-as.data.frame(reshape2::melt(df.matrix, na.rm=T))
        write.csv(df.matrix.melt, file="subjects/Subject_AD_reshaped.csv))

}
```

This code doesn't work mainly because R doesn't seem to recognise the AD folder for both input and output. What's the best way to write this for-loop?

Comment: 1) `subj.AD<-file.path(subjects, "AD"`) 2) You are looping over `subjects`, but the variable define in the previous instruction is now the iterating variable (`subj.AD` is never really used) 3) You read `"matrix.csv"` over and over again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the following code will solve the problem.

```
base_path <- "group/S/project1"
subjects <- list.dirs(path = base_path, full.names = TRUE, recursive = FALSE)

for(s in subjects){
  fl <- file.path(s, "AD", "AD.csv")
  df1 <- read.table(fl, sep = ",")
  df1.matrix <- as.matrix(df1)
  is.na(df1.matrix) <- lower.tri(df1.matrix)
  df2 <- as.data.frame(df.matrix)
  df2.melt <- reshape2::melt(df2, na.rm = TRUE)
  out_file <- paste0(basename(s), "_AD_reshaped.csv")
  out_file <- file.path(s, out_file)
  write.table(df2.melt, out.file, sep = ",", row.names = FALSE)
}
```

Comment: I tried this and I get an error saying `Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In write.csv(df.matrix.melt, out_file, sep = ",", row.names = F) :
  attempt to set 'sep' ignored
2: In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
  cannot open file '/group/S/project1//Sub-001/AD/AD.csv/AD.csv_AD_reshaped.csv': Not a directory.` 

It seems to think that AD.csv is a directory and is trying to save the file within that

Comment: @Sid0311 Can you post a small example of the file structure in the question?

Comment: I've now updated the original post to include a snapshot of the file structure

Comment: @Sid0311 If you set `header = F` in `read.csv`, then it's better to use `read.table` with `sep=","`, like I have. Please don't change this.

Comment: I followed your instructions and used read.table but I still get the same error. The last line of the error is `cannot open file '/group/S/project1//Sub-001/AD/AD.csv/AD.csv_AD_reshaped.csv'` - it doesn't seem to be writing the file into a new sub_001_AD_reshaped.csv file, rather it is nesting the output into the AD.csv file (AD.csv/AD.csv_AD_reshaped.csv' - it thinks AD.csv is a directory).

Comment: @Sid0311 My `base_path <- "group/S/project1"` does *not* have a final bar `"/"`, yours has it. Try removing that bar.